# Border is not displaying in bootstrap4? please check the code given below

Tags: html, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

This is piece of my code **class="card border-primary-left shadow h-100 py-2"** When i am trying to run this code then border is not displaying.

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-2"> <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4"> <div class="card border-primary-left shadow h-100 py-2"> <div class="card-body"> <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center"> <div class="col mr-2"> <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Earnings (Monthly)</div> <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$40,000</div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-primary-left shadow h-100 py-2">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
              <div class="col mr-2">
                <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Earnings (Monthly)</div>
                <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$40,000</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

There is no `border-primary-left` class in Bootstrap. Refer to the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/

And since the `.card` already has a border it would be:

```
card border-primary border-bottom-0 border-right-0 border-top-0
```